# Pasting to the last row of a Sharepoint xlsx file using vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy data from a .xlsm to a .xlsx file in SharePoint (SP). My code does several other things for moving data but the issue I am having is getting the source row from 1 doc to another doc in SP.

I am hoping someone can assist.

```
Sub Complete()

Dim tb1 As ListObject, tb2 As ListObject
Dim Lrow As Long, dRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim searchRange As Range, foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String
Dim wb As Workbook, Scwb As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("OI")
mysearch = ws.Range("D4").Value


Set tb1 = ws.ListObjects("OITs")
Set tb2 = wb.Sheets("TDets").ListObjects("OIFinal")
    Lrow = tb2.ListRows.Count

With ws
    .Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End With

tb1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
    NumRows = tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
tb2.DataBodyRange(Lrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
tb1.DataBodyRange.Columns(4).Resize(, 7).ClearContents
tb1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=" & vbNullString

With ws
    .Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End With

With wb.Sheets("CRqs")
    Set searchRange = .Range("G1", .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set Scwb = Workbooks.Open("https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/******/Shared%20Documents/General/NAA.xlsx") 'Opens the doc that I am looking to paste the data in
Set dRow = Scwb.Sheets("AppAccs").Cells(Scwb.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Yes"
            foundCell.Offset(0, -6).EntireRow.Copy _ 'this works copying the source row of data from a reference entered (mysearch)
            dRow ' this now fails with a runtime error 1004
    Else
         MsgBox "We cannot find the ID " & mysearch & " to send. Please check ID."
    End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

If anyone can help or needs any further info please let me know. Thanks,

Comment: Apologies I have edited the above after making a little progress myself.

Comment: Drop the `.Row` from this line `Set dRow = Scwb.Sheets("AppAccs").Cells(Scwb.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` (that line should have given you an error also...) and `Dim dRow As Range`

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you. I did have it correct originally with exception of the .row you pointed out. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.